# Drupal 7 db_error() equivalent?

Tags: 7, database

I'm trying to figure out how to get the last database error after a query fails, and I'm having trouble finding the appropriate function. It seems up until Drupal 7 there was a `db_error()` function that would return the information.

How should I retrieve a database error in Drupal 7?

My code:

```
try {
    $q = db_query($q);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $error = db_error(); // this is what I'd like to do
    $transaction->rollback();
    watchdog_exception('my_module', $e, t('Caught an error: ' . $error));
}
```

I'm aware that I can get some information from the exception, but I'd like to get it directly from the Drupal 7 API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Drupal 7 database API piggy-backs straight onto PDO. It doesn't define its own exceptions, or messages; it actually doesn't even attempt to handle any exceptions, it leaves them for the caller to handle directly.

The most descriptive error message you can get is in the exception object.

```
catch (\PDOException $e) {
  $error = $e->getMessage();
```

Comment: I'm too shy to edit your code, but isn't that `\` in  `\PDOException` a typo?

Comment: @Mołot The \ just denotes that `PDOException` is in the root namespace; a good habit to get into if you use namespaces a lot

Comment: But namespaces exist only in PHP >= 5.3.0 and Drupal 7 requires 5.2.5 - could you at least warn that your code might not work on setups that are perfectly fine for Drupal itself?

Comment: @Mołot I don't think that's necessary; I really hope no-one is using <=PHP5.2 any more (for their sake, not mine). If they are, and they get an exception using this code, I would hope it serves as a wake-up call that they seriously need to upgrade their server or move to a new host as soon as possible. 5.2 has some serious problems and I don't want to encourage its use (quite the opposite), even if it's viable as a technical exercise.

Comment: FYI, [meta thread about syntax highlight](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204415/225745) - I admit it fooled me at first glance.

Comment: @Mołot Nice one, I meant to do that yesterday but forgot :)

Comment: Not what I thought I was looking for, but I really was looking for the Drupal way of doing things. I expected something more specific because I've seen Drupal convenience functions before, and there used to be a specific `db_error()` function.

Comment: @JoBu1324 Because D6 had to support older versions of PHP it couldn't be done like this (hence the helper method). D7 can take advantage of newer language features so it defers to those, and since PDO already defines detailed exception messages I guess the decision was taken not to re-invent that particular wheel. Things like this also makes adoption of Drupal just that little bit easier for incoming PHP developers, which is something they've been trying to do for a while. D8 takes it even further with the "Proudly Invented Elsewhere" attitude, instead of the old "Not Invented Here" mentality

Comment: @Clive That makes sense. Drupal is powerful, but full of quirks, especially to new developers.

Answer (score 1):

the [Past Log](https://drupal.org/project/past) module will log the exception for you,
not sure if the db_error is included like you need.